# Run single JAR simultanously on Sun-Grid Engine

Tags: java, sungridengine

At my university there is a Sun Grid Engine where I need to perform some tests on. These tests are written in Java an therefore I have created a JAR file which, by just executing it, starts the tests. The test reads in a file and performs some computation on it and at the end writes out a txt file with some results. However, every test is having different parameters which I pass in through the Main method of the JAR. After reading in the file, the parameters will give a different output.

Now I wonder, is this possible to accomplish? Can I run the same JAR multiple times knowing that they all need to read in the same (so just one) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Having multiple processes reading the same file is not a problem, even if those processes are not on the same physical machine.

However, make sure you have a different output file per processes.